# PubSub cron job every 5 minutes between 7am and 12:30am

Tags: cron, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

Do I need to write two cronjobs for this? How do I go about doing it using pubsub schedule? Currently I have:

```
const cron = PUB_SUB().schedule('*/5 * * * *');
```

This completes every 5 minutes, but I want something like ('*/5 7-00:30 * * *')

Comment: As noted in the documentation for the schedule function - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions - the `schedule` method actually uses Cloud Scheduler. Cloud Pub/Sub is just the transport. Could you add the [google-cloud-scheduler] tag and remove the [google-cloud-pubsub] tag?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have 1 entry for minutes and 1 entry for hours in the CRON format, you have to define 2 cron

- For the 7 -> 23: `*/5 * * * *`
- for the 00h to 00h30: `0,5,10,15,20,25,30 0 * * *`